# How can I load multiple images in one array to be faded?

Tags: javascript

I have the following code which suppose to load couple of images and then to fade them. But instead to load all images on each fade it loads the same image every time. Does anyone have any idea?

http://jsfiddle.net/7kacz43o/8/

```
var img, i,
    imageCount = [1,2,3,4],
    div = document.getElementById('foo');
console.log(imageCount.length);
for(i = 1; i <= imageCount.length; i++){
    img = new Image();
    img.onload = function() {
        div.appendChild(img);
    };
    img.src = 'http://tdhdemo.com/frames/frame_' + i + '.jpg';
    img.id = "top";
}
```

Comment: I suppose (I really don't sure) that the problem is because JavaScript is asynchronous so the for continue without wait to the onload function end so the only show the last image.

Answer (score -1):

You reuse `img` inside `onload`, which means when the `for` runs for the next index, `img` will be overwritten. In the `onload` event only the last `img` will be appended to the div (4 times, but that results in one image tag).

Since you attach the `onload` function on the `img` itself, you can use `this` to reference the image:

```
img.onload = function() {
    div.appendChild(this);
};
```

---

Another recommendation: Instead of using an array and its `length` to power your `for` loop, why not use a count variable directly?

```
var imageCount = 4;
...
for (i = 1; i <= imageCount; i++) {
```

Comment: if I will use `this` then it will display all images in the same time

Comment: then you maybe don't want the `onload` handler, because that fires when your image has loaded, and it will load regardless of whether you add it to the DOM or not.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a CSS issue. All the pictures are being loaded correctly but only the first one is being transitioned.

Comment: Check the OP's jsfiddle. only the last image (frame_4.jpg) is loaded. The animation ist just never started/resumed. `onload` is not the right tool for the job.

Comment: ok, but if I remove the onload it still load the all images a time

Comment: @MarkusHayner only `img#top` gets animated, you never assign the ID to a different image (which you shouldn't - better use classes for that) - so why should a different image get animated?

If you want to start/stop/restart CSS animations from javascript, you need to do that: https://css-tricks.com/controlling-css-animations-transitions-javascript/

Comment: `img#top` have a `src` where it should load 4 different images. but it display only one, and that one is the last image